# What happens to a person's bitcoins if they should happen to die prematurely?

Tags: inheritance-plan

What happens to a person's bitcoins if they should happen to die prematurely?  Will those coins be lost forever if no one knows that person's wallet info?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Those bitcoins will never be used again unless someone creates a private key that hashes to the same public key.